# Incomplete/inconsistent state in RichCoFlatMapFunction

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a RichCoFlatMapFunction that looks like below. I store state in a `MapState<String, ArrayList<Operand>>`. Operand is a POJO.

I set the state in flatMap1 function and access it at flatMap2. However, I noticed that when I try to print out the content of state from flatMap2, it does not show all of the elements of the MapState.

In flatMap1, where I set the state, I also printed out the content of state right after setOperandState and it shows all the elements unlike in flatMap2.

Note that I tested it with continuous stream. Also, I ran the code on a single key (i.e. datastream results to only one partition). Am I missing something here?

```
public final class OrganizationFilter
    extends RichCoFlatMapFunction<
        Threshold,
        Point,
        Point
    > {

    private transient MapState<String, ArrayList<Operand>> operands;

    private void setOperandsState(Threshold threshold) throws Exception {

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Operand>> newState = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Operand>>();
        // set newState here.

        operands.clear();
        operands.putAll(newState);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        MapStateDescriptor<String, ArrayList<Operand>> operandsDescriptor =
            new MapStateDescriptor<>(
                "operands",
                BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
                TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<ArrayList<Operand>>() {} )
            );

        operands = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(operandsDescriptor);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void flatMap1(Threshold threshold, Collector<Point> out) throws Exception {
        setOperandsState(threshold);

        // Iterated through MapState content. Shows complete elements.

    }
    
    @Override
    public void flatMap2(Point in, Collector<Point> out) throws Exception {
        // Iterated through MapState contents. Shows incomplete elements
        
    }
}
```

Comment: MapState is key-partitioned state, so you will have a separate map for every key. In other words, for flatMap2 to access the MapState stored in flatMap1, the Point in flatMap2 will have to have the same key as the Threshold in flatMap1. If you believe that's the case, please share a more complete, reproducible example.

Comment: It turned out the operands.clear() cleared all of the state for the key. Thanks for reminding me about key-partitioned state. Every time there is a threshold update for the key, everything gets deleted. My intention was to clear the ArrayList only. Works now.